# Nested queries mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

Hi basically I have made a script to show bookings for different apartments

My table is as follows:

```
id | name     | booking | property_id | arrival    | url             | agent | created    | completed | sub_id
1    john doe   1123121   1             2015-08-09   http://some.url   john    2015-08-09   1           876544
2    mike doe   1111121   2             2015-08-10   http://some.url   john    2015-08-09   1           876344
3    sue doe    1331121   3             2015-08-10   http://some.url   john    2015-08-09   1           876321
4    lauren doe 1330021   4             2015-08-10   http://some.url   john    2015-08-09   1           876021
```

I want the output to be like

Property ID 1

- John Doe

Property ID 2

- Mike Doe

Property ID 3

- Sue Doe

Property ID 4

- Lauren Doe

If no booking exists for a property that property should not show

I had some solution with loops but it doesnt work and bookings randomly appear and disappear

```
$getgroups = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT(`property_id`) FROM `Data` WHERE `arrival` >= NOW()");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getgroups)) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($getgroups) != 0) {    
        $property_id = $row["property_id"];
        if ($row["property_id"] == "1") {
            echo "<h3>Property 1</h3>";
        } elseif ($row["property_id"] == "2") {
            echo "<h3>Property 2</h3>";
        } elseif ($row["property_id"] == "3") {
            echo "<h3>Property 3</h3>";
        } elseif ($row["property_id"] == "4") {
            echo "<h3>Property 4</h3>";
        }
    }


    $getbookings = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `Data` WHERE `property_id` = \"$property_id\" AND `arrival` >= NOW() ORDER BY `arrival` ASC");

    echo "<ul class=\"list-group\">";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getbookings)) {
            $numberofitems++;

            $agent = strtoupper(substr($row["agent"],0,3));



            echo "<li class=\"list-group-item\" id=\"" . $row["id"] . "\" ><b>" . $row["name"] . "</b><div class=\"pull-right\"><span class=\"agent hidden-xs hidden-sm badge\" data-agent=\"" . $row["agent"] . "\" data-id=\"" . $row["id"] . "\">$agent</span> <span class=\"hidden-xs hidden-sm label label-primary\">" . $row["booking"] . "</span> <span class=\"hidden-xs hidden-sm label label-info\">$arrival</span> ";
            if ($row["completed"] == "1") {
                if ($row["sub_id"] != "") {
                    echo "<a href=\"\" class=\"label label-success\">Completed</a> ";
                } else {
                    echo "<span class=\"label label-success\">Completed</span> ";  
                }
                echo "<span class=\"incomplete glyphicon glyphicon-remove\" data-id=\"" . $row["id"] . "\"></span> ";
            } else {
                echo "<span class=\"showlink label label-danger\" data-booking=\"" . $row["booking"] . "\">Incomplete</span> <span class=\"complete glyphicon glyphicon-ok\" data-id=\"" . $row["id"] . "\"></span> ";
            }
            echo "<span class=\"delete glyphicon glyphicon-trash\" data-cust_name=\"" . $row["name"] . "\" data-id=\"" . $row["id"] . "\"></span>";
            echo "</div></li>";

    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code. Then we may help.

Comment: i have added my code

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same variable name to store each line from each request. I would encourage you to use "meaningfull" names for variables, like $group and $booking (instead of $row in both cases). But it's a detail.

That said, I think the problem comes from the re-use of the $con connexion handler to database : you do a first request that sends back a handler with some results. Then, with getBookings, you do a second request with the same $con handler and get back some other results. So you erase/replace the first list of results, and the first while loop is corrupted. You need to use another $con handler to not mix both results.

Comment: changed to different $con no difference